# Why symfony 2.7 does not log notice of my controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have action:

```
public function getQuestions2Action()
{
    MY_CONSTANT;
}
```

app/config/config_prod.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: "!event"
```

In /var/log/nginx/error.log I see:

```
2016/01/21 14:39:48 [error] 31596#0: *313 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant MY_CONSTANT - assumed 'MY_CONSTANT' in /var/www/datravel-client-api/src/Datravel/ClientApiBundle/Controller/RestController.php on line 289
PHP message: PHP Stack trace:
PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/datravel-client-api/web/app.php:0
PHP message: PHP   2. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle($request = *uninitialized*, $type = *uninitialized*, $catch = *uninitialized*) /var/www/datravel-client-api/web/app.php:27
PHP message: PHP   3. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle($request = *uninitialized*, $type = *uninitialized*, $catch = *uninitialized*) /var/www/datravel-client-api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2442
PHP message: PHP   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle($request = *uninitialized*, $type = *uninitialized*, $catch = *uninitialized*) /var/www/datravel-client-api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3223
PHP message: PHP   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw($request = *uninitialized*, $type = *uninitialized*) /var/www/datravel-client-api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3072
PHP message: PHP   6. call_user_func_array:{/var/www/datravel-client-api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3110}(*uninitialized*, *uninitialized*) /var/www/datravel-client-api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3110
PHP message: PHP   7. Datravel\ClientApiBundle\Controller\RestController->getQuestions2Action() /var/www/datravel-client-api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3110" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: datravel-client-api.local, request: "GET /api/v1/client/questions2.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9400", host: "datravel-client-api.local"
```

But app/logs/prod.log is empty

```
$ ls -la app/logs/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 lebnik lebnik 4096 дек.  18 14:02 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 lebnik lebnik 4096 янв.  21 12:59 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lebnik lebnik    0 июля  31 17:20 .gitkeep
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lebnik lebnik    0 дек.  18 14:02 prod.log
```

Prod cache was cleared. I expecting logging notice about undefined constant.

$ php5-fpm -v

```
PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1 (fpm-fcgi)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: Start with the obvious - have you cleared the prod cache? What are you expecting to be in the log - are you logging a custom notice?

Comment: 1. prod cache was cleared
2. yes

Comment: Can you put the code for the notice you're trying to log, please - i.e. copy and paste from the controller.

Comment: No problem, all ready.

Comment: I see that the owner of prod.log is "lebnik lebnik". Have you tried to check if there are some problems with permissions?

Comment: I have no any problems with permissions

Comment: @Lebnik you're not logging anything in the controller - just getting the value of a constant. You need to do something like `$this->get('logger')->debug(MY_CONSTANT);`

Comment: @Blowski MY_CONSTANT is not defined. $this->get('logger')->debug('something'); - work perfectly, but I want to know information about my not defined MY_CONSTANT

Comment: Oh I see - you're trying to get Monolog to log a PHP notice? OK, well first check that's logging something by doing the code I mentioned before. If that works, then you'll need to post some more info about your setup - are you using mod_php or FPM? And which version of PHP? Are notices turned on? I can't remember whether Monolog even logs PHP errors by default.

Comment: @Blowski No problem, added, see description.

Comment: I think @federico's answer is right. Either way, the quickest way to check would be to force monolog to log something, check that's appearing in the logs. Then you'll know that it's just that monolog is not logging PHP notices, and I think that might be default behaviour, hence your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the `dev` environment where your application run in "debug mode" (that's mean that `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL` by symfony itself and all the errors are converted into exceptions and logged), in `prod` environment `error_reporting` is whatever you have set in your `php.ini` and <s>php errors are not handled by symfony</s>. PHP however log them in a file specified in [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log), usually `/var/log/httpd/error_log` or `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

If you want to handle in production the php errors to log them by monolog, you can register the  `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener` listener. In your services:

```
 debug.debug_handlers_listener:
     class: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener
     arguments: [~, "@logger", 24575, ~, false]
     tags:
         -  { name: kernel.event_subscriber}
```

`24575` is the output of `E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED`.

### **UPDATE**

I think that, since `debug.debug_handlers_listener` [already exists](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/debug_prod.xml) in both environment, you should create a compiler passes like this:

```
namespace TestBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class DebugHandlersCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->getParameter('kernel.debug')) {
            $definition = $container->findDefinition('debug.debug_handlers_listener');

            // by default is E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR
            $definition->replaceArgument(2, E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
            $definition->replaceArgument(4, false);
        }
    }
}
```

then register it like this:

```
namespace TestBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use TestBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DebugHandlersCompilerPass;

class TestBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        // add this
        $container->addCompilerPass(new DebugHandlersCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

All you need to do now is to change `action_level: error` of `monolog` in your `config_prod.yml` file to `action_level: warning`.

Comment: I can not tell, I've searched but I found nothing. I don't even think that is a good idea to do this in production.. just see your `error_log` file.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error in /var/log/nginx/error.log, saying that MY_CONSTANT is not defined.
I don't know where in your code you defined it(maybe in the superclass or other classes you included?), but I think you cannot get any information other than "you have not defined it", unless PHP parser cannot find it in a proper place.
Maybe you could search your project and find where you define this 'MY_CONSTANT' in a form like 
  `const MY_CONSTANT = xxx`